# Riemann sum ? (AP Calculus)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to understand how this question can be used to illustrate the understanding of Riemann sums. I know the answer is 6, and that is because of horizontal asymptotes, as n approaches infinity. But how does that relate to Riemann sums?
[image: 1]

Comment: The expression in terms of $n$ arises when you set up a Riemann Sum from the function. Depending on the function, formulas described in https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/ typically are used for Riemann sums. That leads to expressions in terms of $n$ like in your problem.

Comment: This exercise is just a convoluted way for asking what is the value of $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2(n+1)(3n+2)}{n^2}$. 
A question which would have been much more interesting is "*which function fulfills these constraints?*", for instance. In such a case, to check that $f(x)=\frac{x^3+3x^2}{2}$ is a correct option is non-trivial, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riemann integrations can be expressed as functions. For instance, we can approximate $\int_0^2 x^2 \, \mathrm dx$ using a right Riemman sum of $n$ subintervals:

\begin{align*}
R &= \frac{2-0}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \big(\frac{2-0}{n} \cdot k\big)^2 \\
&= \frac 2n \sum_{k=1}^n \big(\frac{2k}{n} \big)^2 \\
&= \frac{4 (n+1) (2 n+1)}{3 n^2}
\end{align*}

So this would be what we use to approximate the integral with $n$ subintervals. And the limit of this function as $n \rightarrow \infty$ approaches the true value of the integral:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{4 (n+1) (2 n+1)}{3 n^2} = \int_0^2 x^2 \, \mathrm dx = \frac 83$$

Back to your question now: With your function, that function represents the Riemann sum of some function from $0$ to $2$, i.e.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n+1)(3n+2)}{n^2} = \int_0^2f(x)\, \mathrm dx = 6$$

Answer (score 1):

A definite integral is defined to be the limit of the Riemann sums. So $$\int_0^2f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n+1)(3n+2)}{n^2}=6$$

The horizontal asymptote of the function $g(n)=\frac{2(n+1)(3n+2)}{n^2}$ is also this exact same limit.